# How can I use onkeydown outside of an input element?

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I have points in a JS canvas. I click on them to initiate different functions.
I'm already using right and left clicks, but I'd like to do something different if I'm depressing SHIFT when I left click.

I need to detect onkeydown, but the cursor is not in an input element.
How can I do that?

eg:

```
function getPosition3(event) // to get click position in canvas3
{   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3");
    mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, event); 
    ge3.px = mousePos.x;
    ge3.py = mousePos.y;
    p2g(ge3);       // converts pixels to graphic coordinates ge3.gx & ge3.gy
    closestDist = 5000000;
    chn = -1; // will contain index of the closest hedge to the click
    [nearestX, nearestY, chn] = nearestHedge(ge3.gx, ge3.gy);
    rnddot(ge3, nearestX, nearestY, 4, '#000000', 0);

    if (event.which==3) {popit(chn);} //popup graph on right click 
    else {poptxt(chn);} 
// Here I'd like to detect onkeydown to allow another option

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla javascript:

```
var shiftPressed = false;

document.addEventListener ('keydown', function(event) {
  shiftPressed = event.shiftKey;
});

document.addEventListener ('keyup', function(event) {
  shiftPressed = event.shiftKey;
});
```

Then change your function:

```
if (shiftPressed) {popit(chn);}
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/charlesartbr/6L4juxbk/

Answer (score 2):

Attach the `keydown` and `keyup` events to the `window` with `window.addEventListener("keydown/keyup", ...)` and keep a global variable that traces the shift key pressed status.

Then inside `getPosition3` function just check that variable.

```
var shiftPressed = false;
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
    shiftPressed = ev.shiftKey; // or whatever property. Just written on-the-fly and I'm not sure if is shiftKey.
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev) {
    shiftPressed = ev.shiftKey;
});

function getPosition3(event) {
    // [...]
    // blah blah
    // [...]
    if (shiftPressed) {
        // Things
    }
}
```